# "JAVAVM Not Installed" when running a query with a SEM_MATCH function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to build a simple example using the Graph capabilities in Oracle DB, and hitting a problem running a SPARQL query.  I added some data as shown [in the guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/rdfrm/rdf-semantic-graph-overview.html#GUID-1C7FBA78-BCDC-4E16-A139-2CC3E3AB9CE4), and that seemed to work properly.  Next I tried running a simple SPARQL query using the SEM_MATCH function:

```
SELECT s$rdfterm S, p$rdfterm P, o$rdfterm O
  FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH(
    'SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE {?s ?p ?o.}',
    SEM_Models('harness'),
    null, null,  null, null,
    ' PLUS_RDFT=VC ',
    null, null,
    'RDFUSER', 'NET1'));
```

The result of this is an error:

```
ORA-13199: JAVAVM is not installed
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_MATCH_IMPL_T", line 161
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 17
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_JAVA_STP", line 5
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_RDF_JAVA_STP", line 39
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_MATCH_IMPL_T", line 1952
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_MATCH_IMPL_T", line 148
ORA-06512: at line 4
13199. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    This is an internal error.
*Action:   Contact Oracle Support Services.
```

The error says that JAVAVM is not installed, but as far as I can tell it is - for example, it's listed in the DBA registry:

[image]

And the Java option is set to True:

[image]

Is there some sort of permission that I need to give to the user in order to execute this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed Oracle Spatial, JAVAVM was not installed; I ran into this error and subsequently installed JAVAVM, but it didn't solve the problem.  What did solve it is reinstalling Spatial afterwards, so it seems that JAVAVM must be installed prior to Spatial.